# BGE and Databases

Tags: game-engine

I'm hoping to use Blender and the BGE in a bit of an unusual way.  I am hoping to create an interactive floor plan where I can click on desks and that will present information about the user.

Now I was hoping to store the data in an SQL database.  Is this possible to do?  I have even looked at the possibility of using Blender4Web to run in browser rather than having to run a seperate .exe each time.

If this may even be slightly possible are there any examples?

Many Thanks
Jon

Comment: If you are just using BGE then any Python code you can write will work, connecting/reading/writing to a database. As far as I can tell Blend4Web uses JavaScript in place of python and **should**  be able to load extra javascript that would interface via http/s to a web service with a database behind it. But I cannot see any direct examples.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, the BGE has no build-in connection to databases.

You can use all Python libraries you like. Be aware you need to distribute them with your final application.

I know it is not a step-by-step instruction, but it is a big topic ... at a python forum.

Comment: where can one read about this topic specifically and not deviate so much from python things that are not directly related in a functional way?